# Лексикографически минимальная подстрока являющаяся палиндромом

Tags: python, алгоритм

Есть задача:
[B. Фактор палиндромности](https://yandex.ru/cup/algorithm/analysis/)

```py
def find_pals(string: str) -> list[str]:
    palindroms: list[str] = []
    for char_index in range(len(string)):
        for char_last_index in range(char_index+1, len(string)+1)[::-1]:
            palindrom: str = string[char_index:char_last_index]
            if len(palindrom) > 1 and palindrom[::-1] == palindrom:
                palindroms.append(palindrom)
    return palindroms

#assert sorted(find_pals("baseorlol?civic-nan!")) == ['civic', 'ivi', 'lol', 'nan']

def main():
    pals = find_pals(input())
    print(min(pals) if pals else -1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Почему-то не проходит 5-ый тест. Никак не могу понять почему.
Мой алгоритм прост: перебрать все возможные подстроки строки и проверить, являются ли они палиндромом.

Comment: по заданию нужно найти подстроку _минимальной_ длинны, и только если таковых будет несколько, то выбрать из них лексикографически минимальную, а в вашем решении функция min возвращает просто лексикографически минимальную. но в любом случае ваше решение не проходит из-за превышения по памяти.

Comment: Интересно, почему столько минусов? Суть задачи приведена (точное условие, конечно, не помешало бы), свой код с пояснением есть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если в строке присутствует палиндром, то его подстрокой будет или два символа (для палиндрома с четной длиной) или три символа (*'civic'* -> *'ivi'*).

то есть, для решения этой задачи достаточно пройтись один раз циклом по строке, сравнивая соседние символы, ну и обновлять переменную в которой хранить самый короткий и лексикографически минимальный палиндром.

такое решение проходит все тесты, ваше же решение (если исправить в нем проверку на минимальность) не проходит из-за превышения по памяти.

Comment: `5 wrong-answer 39ms / 3.21Mb`

Comment: по времени и памяти все проходит, но почему-то ответ неверный

Comment: @LINUX_ADMIN пятый тест не проходит потому что функция min возвращает лексикографически минимальную строку, а не самую короткую ('abc' < 'bb'). Если это исправить (добавить в min соответствующий аргумент key), то ваш код на 14-ом тесте превышает лимит по памяти.

Answer (score 0):

сложность вашего алгоритма `O(n^2)`

вам же требуется найти палиндром МИНИМАЛЬНОГО размера, поэтому можно ввести несколько оптимизаций

1. чтобы проверить слово на палиндром не надо сразу его переворачивать, проверьте сначала 1 и последнюю буквы и только после совпадения делайте полную проверку на палиндром
2. не надо искать все палиндромы, как только нашли палиндром размера `size`, то не стоит дальше искать палиндромы размера `size + 1`

и уже среди этих минимальных по размеру палиндромов искать минимальный по лексографике

3. если вначале пройтись по строке и составить словарь `буква: [индексы в строке]`, то тогда еще эффективнее, чем в п.1) можно перебрать потенциальные палиндромы - поскольку надо проверять подстроки от одного индекса до другого